# How to send data from Visual C++ DLL and a C# GUI

Tags: c#, c++, sockets, dll, communication

What is the correct and efficient way to transfer data from a C++ unmanaged DLL to C# Winforms program? When the initiator should be the DLL and the recipient of the information should be the program.
The program can trigger the process for the first time but then the data needs to flow continuously from the DLL to the program.
I tried with Socket but it did not work for me.

[Project description by image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R96u0.png)

I'll try to give more details about my project.
There is a sensor (1) that sends data every 100 MS to service (2).
The service calls a method in the C++ DLL(3) in order to make some calculations.
The result of the calculation is byte array which represent a column of pixels that need to be sent to the C# GUI (4) continuously in order to build a bitmap.
I know I can use a socket but I'm looking for something more elegant, maybe a callback or something else that I can implement.

Comment: There's no way to answer this question, since we have no way of knowing how the DLL is initialized, or how it produces output for consumption.

Comment: @MarkBenningfield , please see my additional answer.

Answer (score 0):

check this link

[Consuming Unmanaged DLL Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/consuming-unmanaged-dll-functions)

you will find your answer depending on what is your case in the link above,. the implementation wont be hard the only twist is that, you need to copy both x64 and x86 version of the dll into your build folder or the machine

Comment: can you look in my additional question?